# Как удалить объект из коллекции объектов?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Пытаюсь удалить так:  `$this->order->products->pop($product);` Удаляю экземпляр модели из элоквент коллекции. Добавлял тем же самым способом(ларавеловским). Вот так: `$this->order->products->push($product);` Во view для удаления передаю объект продукта через маршрут в контроллер. метод: `public function cartRemove(Product $product)`. Когда добавляю продукт, в объект добавляю поле "колличество товара" чтобы можно было добавить несколько. В представлении информация о количестве есть, но если при нажатии на удаление товара, в контроллере уже свойства количества нет. И видимо из за этого не срабатывает pop. Когда контэйнсом проверяю наличие продукта в заказе, всё типо ок. Товар имеется...
Ларавеловский дебагер говорит следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Дамп энд дай, верхнее, это - продукт содержащийся в заказе, нижнее, продукт который пытаюсь удалить. Тот что пытаюсь удалить свойство не имеет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добавление/Удаление.

```
public function removeProduct(Product $product) 
    {
        if($this->order->products->contains($product)){
            $pivot = $this->order->products->where('id', $product->id)->first();
            if($pivot->countInOrder < 2){
                dd($product);
                $this->order->products->pop($product);
            }else{
                $pivot->countInOrder--;
            }
        }
    }
    public function addProduct(Product $product) 
    {
        if($this->order->products->contains($product)){
            $pivot = $this->order->products->where('id', $product->id)->first();
            if($pivot->countInOrder >= $product->count){
                return false;
            }
            $pivot->countInOrder++;
        }else{
            if($product->count == 0){
                return false;
            }
            $product->countInOrder = 1;
            $this->order->products->push($product);
            //dd($this->order->products, $product);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: А смысл передавать в `pop` переменную `$product`? Ты видишь что там аргумент типа `int`?

Comment: Да, вижу, из за форича показалось что он и коллекцию может разбирать. На аргумент не смотрел.

Comment: Значит остаётся только по ключу удалять?

Comment: Если хотите удалить product с коллекции то использовать надо [forget](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-forget) (или [splice](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-splice)), то что вы сейчас делаете - мало того что некорректное, так ещё и не удаление (суто технически - удаление, но совсем не то что нужно)

Comment: Чтож, это сильно меняет дело... По ключу так по ключу. Спасибо за пояснение.